# Restrict results from a Place Autocomplete - GOOGLE API AUTO COMPLETE

Tags: ios, api, autocomplete, ios9

I am using Google API for auto complete suggestions. I am getting all results from Google service.Now I need only CITY STATE and COUNTRY in suggestion and not the whole address of a place.I had referred the developer guide where I get to know, we can restrict suggestion with Places Type. See this link https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types. I am not getting how to set this Type for my suggestion. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

After getting json response from GooglePlace API, format it accordingly as per city,state,country

As per google docs:----

> When the Places service returns results from a details request, it
>   places them within a single result. Each result may contain the
>   following fields:
>
> address_components[] is an array of separate address components used
>   to compose a given address. For example, the address "111 8th Avenue,
>   New York, NY" contains separate address components for "111" (the
>   street number, "8th Avenue" (the route), "New York" (the city) and
>   "NY" (the US state). Each address_component typically contains:
>
> types[] is an array indicating the type of the address component.
>
> long_name is the full text description or name of the address
>   component.
>
> short_name is an abbreviated textual name for the address component,
>   if available. For example, an address component for the state of
>   Alaska may have a long_name of "Alaska" and a short_name of "AK" using
>   the 2-letter postal abbreviation.
>
> formatted_address is a string containing the human-readable address of
>   this place. Often this address is equivalent to the "postal address,"
>   which sometimes differs from country to country. This address is
>   generally composed of one or more address_component fields.